# i can use this 'zipme' to download source code from gae , but can not i download another file around me

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download, zip, parent

i follow  this article : [zipme](http://www.manatlan.com/blog/zipme___download_sources_of_your_gae_website__as_a_zip_file)

and i download my file successful , and i want to download another file that ex: the parent file

so i change this:

```
dirname=os.path.dirname
folder = dirname(__file__)
```

to

```
dirname=os.path.dirname
folder = dirname(dirname(__file__))
```

but the error is :

```
firefox can't find the file
```

why ？

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get the error, because something fails in the script and it won't return a valid ZIP file back in the response.

The most probable reason is because your `zipme.py` will be in the root of your application. So if you try to get the parent folder of your root folder (returned by `dirname(__file__)`) it will fail because there is no parent folder (or at least not accessible by your code).

As far as I can see there would be no reason to execute the code you want to execute, because the original `dirname(__file__)` should already ZIP all your application's files.